# How do I maximize a function in Mathematica which takes in a variable length list as input?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a time-series like function which gives an output based on a
list of real numbers(i.e. you can run the function on a list of
1,2,3,... real numbers). The issue I'm encountering is how to maximize
the function for a given list length(subject to a set of constraints).
I could fix the function to a fixed number of real numbers(i.e. `f[x_Real, y_Real]` 
instead of `f[x_List]`) and treat `x` and `y` as the first
two elements of the list, and call `Maximize` on the function, but this
is not really elegant. I want to be able to easily change the number
of elements in the list.

What is the best way to optimize a function like I described, which
takes a list as an argument, for a fixed list length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pure function with a `SlotSequence` (usually spelled `##`) argument, like so:

```
In[1]:= f = With[{r = Total[{##}^2]}, Sin[r]/r]&;
In[2]:= NMaximize[f[x,y,z], {x,y,z}]
Out[2]= {1., {x -> -0.0000402914, y -> 0.0000278573, z -> -0.0000765568}}
```

**EDIT:**

1. Like `##`, `xs` will be bound to a [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html), not a `List`, so `Total[xs]` won't work. `Plus[xs]` or `Plus[##]` would.
2. I prefer pure functions instead of `DownValues` for simple things, because they're the simpler construct. Some of this is habit, because in older versions of Mathematica you could get better performance out of pure functions. Using a pure function instead of `DownValues` is still a good way to indicate that you aren't doing anything fancy with pattern-matching dispatch or non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Why not `f[xs___] := With[{r=Total[xs]}, Sin[r]/r]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can define a function with an unspecified number of inputs with a double underscore:

```
f[in__] := Mean[{in}]
f[5, 6]
f[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Use three underscores to denote zero or more arguments:

```
g[x_, y_, z___] := {{x}, {y}, {z}}
g[5, 6]
g[1, 2, 3, 4]
```